# Video is not getting played in Webview in windows phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to build an app for a website and i am using `WebView` to open the website in a phone. Now the problem is that website has videos and those videos are not getting played.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem and how to manage a medias from `WebView`

Thanks

Comment: What's the format/media type of video?

Comment: .flv format of the video

Answer (score 3):

`.flv` (Flash videos) requires Flash player to play. `WebView` of WinRT doesn't has Flash support. So you are out of luck. Better to go for MP4 or WMV v

Comment: is their any way to play flash videos by adding any libraries or something

Comment: No, it's not possible.